# Better approach to call external API in apache beam

Tags: design-patterns, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have 2 approaches to initialize the `HttpClient` in order to make an API call from a ParDo in Apache Beam.

**Approach 1:**

Initialise the `HttpClient` object in the `StartBundle` and close the `HttpClient` in `FinishBundle`. The code is as follows:

```
public class ProcessNewIncomingRequest extends DoFn<String, KV<String, String>> {
        
        @StartBundle
        public void startBundle() {
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                       .uri(URI.create(<Custom_URL>))
                                       .build();

        }
        
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(){
            // Use the client and do an external API call
        }

        @FinishBundle
        public void finishBundle(){
             httpClient.close();
        }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Have a separate Class where all the connections are managed using the connection pool.

```
public class ExternalConnection{

       HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
       HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                       .uri(URI.create(<Custom_URL>))
                                       .build();
       
       public Response getResponse(){
             // use the client, send request and get response 
       }
       
}

public class ProcessNewIncomingRequest extends DoFn<String, KV<String, String>> {
        
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(){
             Response response = new ExternalConnection().getResponse();
        }
}
```

Which one of the above 2 approaches are better in terms of performance and coding design standards?

Comment: Note that the "Approach 2" as written is not actually pooling connections, but I assume that's just for brevity of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either approach would work fine; the `StartBundle/FinishBundle` one is more contained IMHO but has the disadvantage of not working well if your bundles are very small. An even better approach might be to use DoFn's `SetUp/TearDown` which can span an arbitrary number of bundles, but is tied to the lifetime of the DoFn (leveraging the pooling of DoFn instances the Beam SDKs already do).